# What is onAdDismissedFullScreenContent on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

Is the function onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() working when the user closes the add or it works when the ad did not appear? I do not understand very well the meaning of dismissed in this context. The second question is, is it mandatory to put inside this onAdDismissedFullScreenContent function the following code? What is the intention of the following code? Could I put nothing on this function? Thanks in advance

```
onAdDismissedFullScreenContent(){
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the first question**

Yes, this method `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` is user closes the full screen ad content.

And if the ad failed to show full screen content the method

`onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError)` will be called.

You can check the public method summery for FullScreenContentCallback [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/FullScreenContentCallback#public-method-summary)

**And for your second question,**

No, it's not mandatory to set anything inside these functions.

and the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityWorkout.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

will open an activity called **ActivityWorkout** when the ad is closed.

I hope I answered your questions, Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, and should I put something on this else when the interstitialad is null? :       if (mInterstitialAd != null) {//code of showing add } else{//should I put something here if the InterstitialAD ==null like starting a new activity or is it OK if I do nothing if the intertitialad is null? }

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, home.class);
currentActivity.startActivity(intent);